# How insert a value only for Null set in a column in a table in MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql

I am facing a small problem in updating a value in a `column` in a table in MysqlDatabase.

```
UPDATE table_name  
SET Column_name = "572" 
where column_name is  null;
```

Can any help me what is wrong in this statement.

I am new to MySQL.

Thank you

Comment: you edited question, that great. Can you please paste error?

Comment: in the first i gave the entire detail of my sql statement ( Orginal table name and so  on .....)that why i edited my question.......

Comment: yes the second one looks more specific then first one. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting data not updating.

For update you have to use update command.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET col_name= 'col_value'
WHERE col_name IS NULL
```

or

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET col_name= 'col_value'
WHERE col_name=''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE BR294_VWAD 
    SET Lok_Nr = 'New Value'
      WHERE Lok_Nr IS NULL
```